# r(DEA) and r(DeaR) problems on R

Tags: r

I am using library (rDEA) and (DeaR) as I work on R.

When I use the following command:

```
robust16_i_r = dea.robust (X=X16, Y=Y16, model="output", RTS="variable", B=500, alpha=0.05, bw="bw.ucv", bw_mult = 1)
```

I get an answer: Error in bw.ucv(delta_hat_2m) : need at least 2 data points

I tried to change my model from output to input and vice versa and it worked for one of the two lines where I was getting that error; but I am still experiencing problems with the other one. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Learn to properly format code blocks. And read [MCVE] and [ask] so people will have a chance to help you. Voting to close since there's no way this debugging question can be answered with anything other than speculation given the lack of reproducible representation of the X and Y arguments.